# How to maintain variables and still have a decent URL when using Server.Transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response.redirect

I have a ASP.NET project where some data needs to be preserved when navigating between different pages of the application. I settled on using Server.Transfer() to accomplish this.

```
public BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<NotyMessage> NotyMessageQueue = new List<NotyMessage>();

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
            var oldpage = PreviousPage as BasePage;
            if (oldpage != null)
                {
                NotyMessageQueue.AddRange(oldpage.NotyMessageQueue);
                }
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateurl", "window.history.pushState('','', '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "');", true);
            }

        foreach (NotyMessage message in NotyMessageQueue)
            {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), message.RenderScript(), true);
            }
}
```

Other pages can make use of this class by inheriting from it, and adding a `NotyMessage` to the `NotyMessageQueue`. If for some reason that page needs to send the user to another page, they can use `Server.Transfer("otherpage.aspx");` and their messages will be preserved.

I have a couple concerns with this. This has a drawback in that it doesn't update the client side URL. I like the URL to be correct, in case the user wants to come back to that page or provide it to someone else as a link. That's why I added the "updateurl" JavaScript, but it doesn't play well with ASP.NET friendly names. For example, if the server transfers the request to "~/otherpage.aspx" it should display to the user as "~/otherpage". I can't figure out how to do that, short if just manually chopping the extension off, which seems like a bad idea. Is there a way to handle the URL so that it respects ASP.NET friendly names? Or is there some other way I can do this without using `Server.Transfer()`?

Comment: any reason of why you don't use Session to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. So with a Session, that's not particular to a certain instance of a response/request lifecycle. I need the messages to be routed to the correct response in order to not confuse the user. If you can come up with a valid solution using Session that sucessfully routes the URL's to the correct response and maintains the URL's without looking like a giant hack (I've seen several people attempt to do this with Session and it never turns out good) then I'm all ears :)

Comment: Well, if it is not user-specific stuff you can then use Application variables

Comment: That's even worse than Session!